# Extracting real-time server-side data for client-side application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket

I'm using websockets to send data from the server to the client. This works fine so for example I can display messages the server is sending to the client as they are received. This is the partial javascript I use:

```
    ws.onmessage = function(evt){
            $("#display").append(evt.data + "<br />");

            console.log(evt.data);
```

This is the data displayed:

```
{"place": {"full_name": "Northampton, Northamptonshire"}, "coordinates": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-0.9003352, 52.2467064]}}
```

But if I just wan the coordinate information i,e, the longitude and latitudes then the web console error message is:

```
TypeError: evt.data.coordinates is undefined @ http://localhost:8888/:34
```

I'm trying to get this data by doing:

```
    ws.onmessage = function(evt){
            var coordinates = evt.data.coordinates.coordinates;
            console.log(coordinates);
```

I'm a newbie to javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Your data are strange. Why those 'u' ?

Comment: Sorry in the browser it's received as: {"place": {"full_name": "Northampton, Northamptonshire"}, "coordinates": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-0.9003352, 52.2467064]}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`evt.data` is a JSON string. You have to parse it :

```
ws.onmessage = function(evt){
   var msg = JSON.parse(evt.data);
   var coordinates = msg.coordinates.coordinates;
```

Comment: Spot on....I should have realized I was sending the data in JSON format. Thanks for your help.